# Can Solr results be grouped and limited to a subset of each group?

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

I'd like to display the top 5 results from different content types stored in Solr. Is it possible to group by a defined field and limit each group to a number of results, similarly to a "first N rows" SQL query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Field collapsing / Result grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing).